# How to Redirect Route 53 subdomain to subdirectory of your website

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a domain on **Godaddy** and using amazon **Route 53** hosting. I want to create a subdomain and make it point to a subdirectory in my site. How is it possible?

**I Have Tried**

- Using S3 bucket, but s3 settings say host a static site. My site isn't static so I believe that option won't work
- I have added a subdomain on route 53 with the help of this article
  [How do I create a subdomain for a domain hosted through Route 53?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-subdomain-route-53/)
  and then changed my server settings to make new domain point to a subdirectory using this answer
  [How to point domain name to Amazon EC2 subdirectory](https://superuser.com/questions/648068/how-to-point-domain-name-to-amazon-ec2-subdirectory). But it didn't work. Web page shows DNS server not found

Any kind of help will be appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

DNS resolves a domain name to the IP address of your server. It only resolves the first part of a URL that defines the server -- it is not involved in the remainder of the URL.

For example:

```
http://example.com/path/index.html
```

DNS converts `example.com` into the IP address of the server. The request for `/path/index.html` is then sent to port 80 of that server.

**Therefore, it is not possible to configure Amazon Route 53 (nor any DNS server) to point to a subdomain of your site.**

You could, however, configure your web server to **recognize requests going to different domain names** and serve different content to the user. For example:

```
http://images.example.com/foo.jpg
```

DNS will resolve `images.example.com` to the same IP address, but the web server can notice that the original request was to `images.example.com`, so it should serve a different set of content, or content from a desired subdirectory. This configuration would be done within your web server. If that's what you'd like to do, please consult your web server documentation or search the web for that topic.

Comment: I got it. How to make my Route 53 recognize the subdomain?

Comment: Actually the second point that I have tried is exactly what you have explained. Create a sub domain in Route 53 and then edit your server to redirect it. The issue is somewhere in my implementation and that's where I need help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The solution was for me to set the load balancer (Application Load Balancer) as target for sub.mydomain.com and then in the load balancer listener rules, add a rule for the subdomain (as host header value) with a redirect.